# Am I interpreting correctly this NMF analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, biostatistics, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I have to analyse a set of biological data and I am applying a Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NMF) Approach. Given a 366 x 144 dataset, I am reasoning about overfitting and the correct rank r to choose.
We have three possibilities : Brunet (2004), Hutchins (2008) and Frigyesi (2008). If I have to rely on Brunet I would choose r = 7 because it is the first values after which I can see a decrease in the cophenetic value. As far as I can see, I see no inflection point so I cannot see any applicability for Hutchins. The unique doubt that I have is about Frigyesi: the slope of the real data seems to be minor that randomized data's slope after r= 8. Given that r= 7 explains already the ~ 96% of the variance (see evar) is it correct to take 7 instead than 8?

[image: NMF rank survey]

Edit (as asked) 6/10/2020
References

Brunet J, Tamayo P, Golub TR and Mesirov JP (2004). "Metagenes and molecular pattern discovery
using matrix factorization." _Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United State

Hutchins LN, Murphy SM, Singh P and Graber JH (2008). "Position-dependent motif characterization using non-negative matrix factorization."

Comment: Can you include, with all details, the references you mention? You get no responses probably because very few people will understand what you talk about ...

Comment: I will edit in the afternoon. Thank you for the suggestion!